# Leaflet search popup

Tags: leaflet

I combined two plugins: Leaflet search and cluster. But I want search points and automatically move to a location and view its popup.  But it is not working, I can search, move to location but there's no automatic popup.

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer, marker) {
        layer.bindPopup( "ID vzorku "    + feature.properties.catalogNumber +
"</br> nadmořská výška "+ feature.properties.elevation + " m n.m."+
"<br> průměrná roční teplota "+feature.properties.t_year +"°C"+
"<br>  roční úhrn srážek    "+feature.properties.preci2 +" mm " );
    }
});
markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

map.addLayer(markers);

//vytvoření panelu pro vyhledávání
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: markers,
    propertyName: 'catalogNumber',  // pole přes které se vyhledává
circleLocation: true,
marker: false,


moveToLocation: function(latlng, catalogNumber, map) { console.log(latlng); map.setView(latlng, 10); } 
});

searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {

    //console.log('search:locationfound', );



        e.layer.openPopup("OBJECTID");

}).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {

featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {   //restore feature color
featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Once you have the selected feature, use the .fire('click'); it's like you clicking on a feature with the mouse. In my code 'a' is the selected feature, I also use this to zoom to the selected feature.

```
// fire off click event and zoom to polygon
function polySelect(a){
    map._layers[a].fire('click');
    var layer = map._layers[a];
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}// END...fire off click event and zoom to polygon
```

Comment: Online demo using Leaflet search (Search for 'red') http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/Baseball2.html  I also have a write up of using JQuery Autocomplete as a search tool if you need options http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/index.html